# Little Graph Theory Problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite graph and let $H_1,\ldots, H_n$ be some distinct subgraphs with the same number of vertices, and with the property that each edge of $G$ belongs to the same number of the $H_i$.

Must all of the $H_i$ have the same number of egdes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $G$ be the disjoint union of $H_1=C_5$ and $H_2=P_5$.
Every edge of $G$ belongs to exactly one of the $H_i$ and the $H_i$ have the same number of vertices, but not the same number of edges.

Comment: To me $C_5$ and $P_5$ have the same number of edges, but that might be a notation thing. Anyway, it works equally well for a $3$-cycle and a $2$-path, so thanks :)

Comment: Standard notation says $C_5$ is a cycle with 5 vertices, which has 5 edges, and $P_5$ is a path with 5 vertices, which has 4 edges. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph.